# Estimation of Cumulative value every 3 months in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID  Date    Prod
1   1/1/2009    5
1   2/1/2009    5
1   3/1/2009    5
1   4/1/2009    5
1   5/1/2009    5
1   6/1/2009    5
1   7/1/2009    5
1   8/1/2009    5
1   9/1/2009    5
```

And I need to get the following result:

```
ID      Date          Prod  CumProd
1     2009/03/01      5       15   ---Each 3 months
1     2009/06/01      5       30   ---Each 3 months
1     2009/09/01      5       45   ---Each 3 months
```

What could be the best approach to take in SQL?

Comment: pleaese provide the table info and data in formated way. it is difficult to understand from this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you want to aggregate per quarter and product or per quarter for one particular product or how come there is a product in your results?

Comment: And yes, what have you tried, where are you stuck? Would you know how to do the same per month and don't know how to do this per quarter? Or don't you know how to aggregate data at all or what other issue are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below - using window function

**[DEMO Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=55b1940ec15343b456fa6b3f49aa0c13)**

```
select * from
(
select *,sum(prod) over(order by DATEPART(qq,dateval)) as cum_sum,
row_number() over(partition by DATEPART(qq,dateval) order by dateval) as rn
from t
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just filtering on the month number?

```
select t.*
from (select id, date, prod, sum(prod) over (partition by id order by date) as running_prod
      from t
     ) t
where month(date) in (3, 6, 9, 12);
```